# UWP app crashes with STOWED_EXCEPTION shown in dev store

Tags: c#, uwp, crash-reports, uwp-xaml, windows-dev-center

my UWP runs fine on my PC, I downloaded it from store to check it on my pc and it runs fine, but it is **crashing on certain other PCs** for unknown reasons, it crashed on the splash screen and **dev center** is showing me following crash reports.
Please let me know how can I fix or handle these exceptions.

**NOTE**

"**Fluenttt"** is the namespace of my app project. 
[image: Exceptions Screenshot]

Also note that dev center has no data in log for these exceptions. or no stacktrace shown.

Comment: Does it tell you what the OS version is? "Fluent" is name of the new UI in Fall Creators Update, so this is likely a crash on an insider build (it could be an OS bug)

Comment: No actually my own machine is running on insider build and app works fine on my pc, but one of my friends has anniversary version of win 10. which is min target version of my app, and app crashes on his pc as well. Fluenttt in this error is with 3 "t" and that is actually name of my project which I packaged to the store. Also I packaged only for x86 and x64 and not for ARM. can that be a reason of this crash? or I think ARM PCs should not be able to download my app right?

Answer (score 1):

ARM can't be the reason of your crash. ARM package is for mobile device and if you don't upload it when you publish your app, your app won't be available to customer on mobile device in Store.

Without your app, it's hard to tell the reason just according to your failure name. But you could add an [UnhandledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_UnhandledException) event to notify your app about exceptions encountered by the XAML framework or by Windows Runtime in general that haven't been handled by your app code.

Additionally, you could also use [Custom event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/log-custom-events-for-dev-center) to log the event or activity in your app and you can review the occurrences for your custom events in the **Custom Events** section of the Usage report in dashboard.